# Publish a basic MVC3 application, access is denied

Tags: asp.net, deployment, asp.net-mvc-3

I just made my first MVC3 app, and I thought it would be fun to upload it to my web hotell. So I did a publish locally in visual studio and then transfered the published files to them over ftp. They have support for MVC3, so there shouldn't be any problems there. But what I get when I try to go the the page I get an 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Please help, I've tried to add the:

```
  <authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some misconfiguration of the application in IIS. Try setting the application pool to run in Integrated Mode (vs Classic Mode). Also try [bin deploying](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) in case your hosting provider doesn't have MVC 3 installed on the server.

Remark: you absolutely don't need the `<authorization>` tags in your web.config. That's no longer used in MVC. Authorization in ASP.NET MVC is handled by decorating your controllers/actions with the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Haha, wow thank you very much, the integrated did the trick! Now I need to find out the difference between integrated and classic. But that you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
 <remove name="ServiceModel"/>
 <add name="mvc" type="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"/>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error when for some reason routing is not configured right in IIS, are you certain that your host supports MVC 3?

Comment: Well, they do told me that, I know that MVC 2 is working. But Wouldn't I get another error if they didn't support mvc3? Seems like some kind of user rights?